# Build Cyanogenmod12 for unofficial devices

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I am trying to build cyanogenmod 12 from rom source. I have succesfully built the rom for nexus 5 (hammerhead), following the instructions in their wiki.

But when I am trying to build cm12 for devices like samsung grand duos, I am unable to proceed, as I can't find the device name in the lunch menu.

How do I build the rom for such unofficial devices? What is the procedure?

Comment: do you can build it for you device? I need help.... My device haven't source of kernel... could you guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [these](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_porting_intro) instructions.  It, along with the rest of the [development section](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Development) of the wiki, should have the info you need.

Comment: The cyanogenmod mod page is down, can you send me the information?? Thank you @fattire

Comment: The the current wiki page is http://wiki.lineageos.org/ but it's not yet restored to that location.  For now I've [restored the single page](http://fat-tire.github.io/porting-intro.html) in question (warning:  very quick and dirty-- ugly page!), but there were many more resources on the old wiki which I hope make it back online soon.